# How to wait a result from the EDT?

Tags: java, swing

For test things, I want to launch a process on the swing edt, and wait for a result.

Usualy, I do that with a invokeAndWait. But perhaps is it possible to use a FutureTask, and launch this task on the EDT ??

Is it possible, and have you an exemple of (my) idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`EventQueue.invokeAndWait` behaves much the same as a lock. A lock with an awful lot inside, which is against the usual advice to keep short. It therefore is prone to cause deadlocks, and I'd recommend avoiding it.

Run a task on the EDT with `EventQueue.invokeLater`. Have that task run a task on your thread using a task queue. (Only avoid statics, and I suggest using a non-static wrapper around `invokeLater` so that you can test and monitor).

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you know that Swing component manipulation must be done in the event dispatch thread, but the simple answer is **no**, you never want to start a long-running task or wait on locks while in the EDT.  The EDT should always remain highly responsive.  Also, as an aside, `invokeAndWait()` cannot be called from the EDT, for obvious reasons.

Take a look at this old article about [Threads and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) - the basic principles still apply.

You have several options open to you.  You can simply create a new `Thread`, `Runnable` or `FutureTask` to run on an `Executor`, and call `invokeAndWait()` only when necessary to update components (but if you can get away with it, `invokeLater()` is better).  You could also use a `SwingWorker` (also in the article), which provides additional useful ways of interfacing between your thread and the EDT with a proper degree of separation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't want to wait inside the edt, I want to wait outside the EDT. For instance : I launch an invokeLater to show a JFrame, an other to show a button in this frame and so on ; and I want to make a test at the end af all the pending edt. How is it possible ?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use `invokeAndWait` outside the EDT, as long as the inner code doesn't take too long to run.  What do you mean by 'make a test at the end of it all'?  Your intentions might be clearer if you post your code in the question.